# Ошибка IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

Суть игры заключается в том, что есть 3 круга красного цвета, случайным образом выбирается один из них и закрашивается в зеленый. В течении определенного промежутка времени (который постепенно будет уменьшаться) необходимо клацнуть на него мышкой, если этого не происходит, выбирается другой случайный круг. Вот, что у меня получилось

```
package yourreaction;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Random random;
    public static int randomNum;

    NewThread() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    public void run() {
        randomNum = random.nextInt(YourReaction.AmountOfCircles);
        YourReaction.circle[randomNum].setFill(Color.GREEN);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {System.out.println("IE");}
    }
}
/*
class ProcessThread implements Runnable {
    Random random;
    public static int randomNum;

    ProcessThread() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    public void run() {
        randomNum = random.nextInt(YourReaction.AmountOfCircles);
        YourReaction.circle[randomNum].setFill(Color.GREEN);
    }
}*/

public class YourReaction extends Application {
    Scene scene;
    VBox vbox;
    public static Circle[] circle;
    public static final int AmountOfCircles = 3;
    public final int radius = 20;
    public int score = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        vbox = new VBox(5);

        scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 250);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        Button B_Start = new Button("Start");
        Button B_Exit  = new Button("Exit");

        B_Start.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                GameProcess();
            }
        });

        B_Exit.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me)  {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(B_Start, B_Exit);

        stage.show();
    }

    public int GameProcess() {
        vbox.getChildren().clear();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        scene.setRoot(hbox);

        circle = new Circle[AmountOfCircles];

        for(int i = 0; i < AmountOfCircles; i++) {
            circle[i] = new Circle();
            circle[i].setRadius(radius);
            circle[i].setFill(Color.RED);
            hbox.getChildren().add(circle[i]);
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(new NewThread());

        while(score < 3) {
            t.start();

            circle[NewThread.randomNum].setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    circle[NewThread.randomNum].setFill(Color.RED);
                    score++;
                }
            });
            /*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timedir);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {System.out.println("Interrupted exception!");}*/
        }

        //eventThread.interrupt();

        return score;
    }
}
```

При запуске, после нажатия кнопки start выдает следующее:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
at yourreaction.YourReaction.GameProcess(YourReaction.java:109)
at yourreaction.YourReaction$1.handle(YourReaction.java:74)
at yourreaction.YourReaction$1.handle(YourReaction.java:72)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Нельзя блокировать UI поток. Нельзя обновлять UI не из UI потока.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? Только недавно начал потоки учить.

Comment: а по какой книге вы учите?

Comment: Java. Методы программирования.- Блинов, Романчик.

Comment: возьмите лучше Head first Java

Answer (score 1):

У вас поток t стартуется бесконечно.

```
while(score < 3) {
    t.start();
    ...
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, как сделать, чтобы этот поток работал вместе с циклом?

Comment: Не вдаваясь в логику программы могу посоветовать обернуть while в еще одни поток через лямбда-выражение: "new Thread(() -> {while(...) {...}}).start();". А все изменения относящиеся к JavaFx внутри этого вспомогательного потока нужно будет делать через другое лямбда-выразение Platform.runLater(...): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-

Comment: Platform.runLater нужен потом, что JavaFx можно изменять только в JavaFx потоке. Возможно можно было бы обойтись и без дополнительных Thread, а использовать http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html В случае с Timeline задачи с определенным временным интервалом запускаются в самом JavaFx потоке, что позволяет избежать использования Platform.runLater. Но главное помнить, что JavaFx поток нельзя останавливать ни в коем случае, иначе ваш интерфейс повиснет, JavaFx использует один поток, которому вы можете ставить короткие задачи по изменению объекто интерфейса.